# How to get image text from google vision api using client library with apikey and oauth credentials

Tags: google-cloud-platform, nlp, google-translation-api

I have requirement to pass APIkey and OAuth credentials to get image text using google vision api .net client library. How to create and call methods to pass apikey and oauth credentials in client library?

Below for service account but need examples for API key and OAuth credentials.

```
client = ImageAnnotatorClient.Create();
logos = client.DetectLogos(inputImage);
```

Comment: AFAIK, you don't need API key. Can you share the curl call that you perform?

Comment: Hi thank you for your reply @guillaume blaquiere. Actually am using c sharp .Net GCP api client libraries( Google.Cloud.Vision.V1) to call api's, i have not used and tried curl. I required to provide options to user for pass multiple credentials like api, oauth and service accout to access the gcp api based on user needs. I could not found any reference to pass apikey or oAuth credentials to access api. Kindly guide me if you have anything about it.

Comment: Do you have an error? Where are you stuck? Because I don't understand why you want an APIKey instead of using an access token, I don't really know what it doesn't work.